# Homepage Visualforce Component - Adjusting Width

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

i have the following problem:

I made an Homepage Visualforce component to show some info to my customers.

```
<apex:page controller="UserApprovalProcessCtrl" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" >
<apex:pageBlock html-width="100%">
 my content
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The problem i'm facing is the following:

if I set the attribute showHeader="true" on the apex:page element in my VF page the result is the following:

[image]

As you can see the component width is different from the others... 
If i set the attribute showHeader="false" the problem doesn't occur anymore. But i don't want to do that because i want my component to have the Home tab style.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a 10px margin applied to the page component via the standard style sheets class **hasMotif** (you can check this via your browser dev tools)

you can override it in your page.. something like below.

Note : overriding standard css might not be a proper or better way, thou it will get you the 100% width you wanted.. do it at your own risk

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" >
<style>
.hasMotif
{
margin : 0px;
}
</style>
<apex:pageBlock html-width="100%">
 my content
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks man, right now this is the best work-around i found on the net. 
I'll let you know if i'll be able to solve this in a proper way ;)

Answer (score 1):

showHeader and sideBar should be set to false. It works !